# Getting Zend framework up and running

Tags: php, zend-framework, ubuntu-13.04

This might be the wrong place to ask but a little help would be appreciated.

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and trying to get the Zend Framework up and running. I followed all the directions for installation but it does not render the welcome page just gives me a black page when I am on `/public/index.php`. Any reason for that? If anyone this problem I would love some help.

Comment: [Enable error reporting](http://blog.flowl.info/2013/enable-display-php-errors/), look into the logs (`/var/log/apache*|http*`), is Zend enabled in `phpinfo();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DanFromGermany, I was getting this error  `require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ......`

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to see /public/index.php in url. Check the virtual host definitions.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Comment: have vhosts set up that way, so when i go to my 127.0.1.1 or whatever alias, still the same thing.